# How can I find the $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb Z_{20}}(5\mathbb Z_{20})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$. but I cant prove it. Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- the $\mathbb{Z}_n$- and $\mathbb{Z}$-module endomorphisms of a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module are the same,
- $d\mathbb{Z}_n\cong\mathbb{Z}_{n/d}$ as abelian groups when $d\mid n$,
- any homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is determined by where it sends a generator